# Spring AMQP multiple threads calling into message listener

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a DirectRabbitListenerContainer (created through a DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory) where I have a MessageListener setup through a MessageListenerAdapter.

The issue I am have is that sometimes the same message from RabbitMQ will arrive at the MessageListener multiple times by different threads.

`[2020-06-16 11:12:45,910] INFO com.something.MyMsgListener [pool-1-thread-3] Message ID:bca8cdcc-385a-4847-bd15-50e8936
  [2020-06-16 11:12:45,910] INFO com.something.MyMsgListener [pool-1-thread-8] Message ID:bca8cdcc-385a-4847-bd15-50e8936`

This is causing a lot of problems for the application I am writing. I am wondering if someone can point out which configuration item is causing this (or can prevent this). On the message producer side, I know only 1 message was produced and sent to RabbitMQ. Sometimes up to 6 threads will process the same message. Sometimes the problem goes away. I don't have a good grasp of why this is happening... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, unless the listener called by `pool-1-thread-3` throws an exception and the message is redelivered.

There is no guarantee that a redelivery will arrive on the same thread since it uses the thread pool managed by the amqp-client.

With the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` and `concurrency=1`, the redeliveries will always occur on the same thread.

Comment: Hi Gary, I'm not trying to get it to always arrive at the same thread. I'm simply trying to ensure that only 1 copy of the message arrives. I don't believe it is a re-delivery because the listener is called at the exact same moment always. Is there something I've done that would cause 1 message to be handled by multiple threads? Thanks!

Comment: If it's not redelivery, the only way I can see it happening is if you have a fanout or topic exchange and you have multiple queues bound to it and you are consuming from all of those queues. I don't see any other way it could happen; edit the question to show your code and configuration. It would be even better if you could post a small project that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'm very embarrassed to say that was the problem - the configuration was wrong and it is a fanout exchange where multiple queues are bound and consumed.